# Change variable in the integral doesn't work

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, trigonometry, change-of-variable

I need to show that for small angles $$f_N\left(\frac{\pi}{2N}\right) \approx \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin(u)}{u}du$$ the only information that I have is that we have $$f_N(x) = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^x\frac{\sin(2Nt)}{\sin(t)}dt$$

**My Attempt**

So I tried witht he change of variable $2Nt = u$ so that $dt = \frac{du}{2N}$ and then substituted in $$f_N(x) = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^x\frac{\sin(u)}{\sin\left(\frac{u}{2N}\right)}\frac{du}{2N} \approx \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^x\frac{\sin(u)}{u}du$$

But then when I plug in $x = \frac{\pi}{2N}$ I get $$f_N\left(\frac{\pi}{2N}\right) \approx \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2N}}\frac{\sin(u)}{u}du$$

> What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't change the upper limit
in the integral.

When $t=x$,
$u = 2Nx$.

Then,
when you put in
$x = \frac{\pi}{2N}$,
you get
$u = \pi$.